# Struggling with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have the following URL

`.co.uk/our-courses/index.php?category=1`

Which I am trying to write as...

`.co.uk/our-courses/1`

I have created and uploaded the following .htaccess file but when I load the page I get 404 not found.  Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong as I just cant see it?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/our-courses/([0-9]+)?$ /our-courses/index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Everything after `our-courses/([0-9]+)` is not present at `our-courses/1` :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález apologize.  I've updated the question.  I left something in there from my last edit.  It still doesn't load.  just simply says 404 error

Comment: If it's at `.htaccess` (as opposed as e.g. httpd.conf) you possibly just need to remove the leading slash from RewriteRule.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález worked perfectly.  can you put that as an aswer so I can accept it.  thank you for your help :)